# While loop responds strangely to non integer

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I have a problem when running this where I was testing to make sure the while loop works. If a non-integer value is inputted for cin << a; the loop will execute endlessly without asking for further values of a, if what is inputted is an integer but not one of those listed it works fine but I want it to account for any input users try. Is there a simple way to fix this? I assume it has something to do with a being an int but I need an int for the switch statement later on.

```
int a;
cout << "What type of game do you wish to  play?\n(Enter the number of the menu option for)\n(1):PVP\n(2):PvE\n(3):EVE\n";
cin >> a;
while (!((a == 1) || (a == 2) || (a == 3)))
{
    cout << "That is not a valid gametype. Pick from the following menu:\n(1):PVP\n(2):PvE\n(3):EVE\n";
    a = 0;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: Wow, so many parentheses! You don't need the ones around the individual `==` tests, and you can get rid of the pair around the three tests by applying De Morgan's theorem: `while (a != 1 && a != 2 && a != 3)` is so much easier to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work:

```
    int a;
cout << "What type of game do you wish to  play?\n(Enter the number of the menu option for)\n(1):Player V Player\n(2):Player vComp\n(3):Comp V Comp\n";
cin >> a;
while (a != 1 && a != 2 && a != 3 || cin.fail())
{
    cout << "That is not a valid gametype. Pick from the following menu:\n(1):Player V Player\n(2):Player vComp\n(3):Comp V Comp\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cin >> a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cin >> a;
```

If this code fails (and it does if you provide non-integer data), the stream will enter an invalid state, and all subsequent calls to `cin >> a` will return immediately with no side-effects, still in its error state.

This is a C++ design decision I don't particularly like (and probably why most people don't like the Streams design in C++), because you'd expect this to throw an error or return to normal afterwards, like in most other languages. Instead, it fails silently, which is the biggest source of many program bugs.

At any rate, there's two possible fixes for this.

The first is to properly check that the stream is still valid. Like so:

```
while (!((a == 1) || (a == 2) || (a == 3)))
{
    cout << "That is not a valid gametype. Pick from the following menu:\n(1):PVP\n(2):PvE\n(3):EVE\n";
    a = 0;
    if(!(cin >> a)) break; //Input was invalid; breaking out of the loop.
}
```

This will break the loop if the input is invalid, but leaves the stream in an invalid state.

The other fix is to reset the stream to a valid state.

```
while (!((a == 1) || (a == 2) || (a == 3)))
{
    cout << "That is not a valid gametype. Pick from the following menu:\n(1):PVP\n(2):PvE\n(3):EVE\n";
    a = 0;
    while(!(cin >> a)) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Please only enter Integers." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The second is usually the approach people need, but there might be situations where the first makes more sense.

Comment: You are, of course, free to dislike the design of C++ streams, but you should not claim to speak for "most people", especially when your objections take the form of statements that clearly show that you don't know what the design goals were and that you don't know how to use them correctly.